# Hibernate saveOrUpdate integrity constraint exception

Tags: hibernate

I am using saveOrUpdate method to store a list of data , the list of data is GETTING STORED but after insertion in the logs I can see exception saying

Could not insert data unique constraint violated (for the unique column in the database)

I don't understand when I am using saveOrUpdate why am I getting this exception additionally the data is getting saved properly which is confusing me further.

The table is independent no relationship with any other table

Comment: show the transactional method and the stacktrace possibly

Comment: @Maciej unfortunately I won't be able to do that

Comment: then change the naming or something.. does not need to be exact